# Not getting individual data using curl

Tags: php, json, rest, curl

i am trying to get indivdual data using curl from this website http://dummy.restapiexample.com/ .. I use the following code to get all data

```
<?php
$url='http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees';
$my_curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($my_curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($my_curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($my_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($my_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($my_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$my_data = curl_exec($my_curl);
$my_json = json_decode($my_data);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($my_json ); echo '</pre>';
?>
```

1) This is working . But i want to get the indvidual data , so i tried to chage url and use the same code

```
$url="http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/1"
```

But it is not working .

2) Also i try to create a new record , **that is working**

```
$data = array("name" => "Hagridbo", "salary" => "123",  "age" => "36");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/create');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

**But how can i get the response like data is inserted ? what data is inserted ?**

Comment: It looks like the details of the web site your using are just examples and even if you go onto the page and click on the links they provide - you get `false`.  So it is more likely their problem not yours.

Comment: so could you please answer for seconf question

Comment: @NigelRen  no it's not. actually employee id's started from `20232` itself . that's why it's not giving data (as OP tried with 1). check here:- http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/20232

Comment: @AlivetoDie just tried that link you posted and I still get `false` as the response. (Edit:) Just did a full list and they now seem to start at 20275

Comment: @AlivetoDie yes . That true , i tried with different id and it is working . So please put this comment in answer section . Also please check my second point also . And i am currently checking how can i update or delete details . So if you can answer this please include all in answer section

Comment: @Manik  in your second code after `$result = curl_exec($ch);`   do `var_dump($result);` and see what it give you. i think it will give you a json data response of added user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1.*** Regarding individual employee data is not coming

If you look to the `http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees`, you will see that employee id 1 is not there. That's why you are not getting any data.

for example check data of this link:- http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/20276

***Also it seems that `v1/employees` API data changing on a regular interval.***

***2.*** Regarding created an employee successfully, but not getting any response.

do `var_dump($result);` after `$result = curl_exec($ch);`and see what it give you. I think it will give you a json data response of added user.

I said it based on details of that API link, check here: http://dummy.restapiexample.com/create

Comment: could you please give example for how to update or delete in http://dummy.restapiexample.com/

Comment: @Manik  check the details of api, it gives you clear picture that what kind of data you need to post, what method you need to use etc.... Do that way

Comment: could you please help , how i can use the postman fro this operation